# How to works with polynomials like base of real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, real-numbers

We have: 
$$ (x^2 + x − 1, 2x + 2, −x^2 − 3) $$
How can I work with that to know if this is base of $\mathbb R^{≤2}$ ? I dont know how to create good matrix for this polynoms.

Comment: Remember that a matrix of coordinate vectors always, in a sense, *describes/compares* a set of vectors **in terms of a known basis**. In $\Bbb{R}^n$ we are comparing to the standard basis $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$. In a polynomial space, see user's answer for a standard basis :-)

Comment: But, it also behooves me to point you to [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually standard basis is $\{1,x,x^2\}$ therefore

- $x^2+x-1=-1\cdot (1,0,0)+1\cdot (0,1,0)+1\cdot(0,0,1) \equiv(-1,1,1)$
- $2x+2=2\cdot (1,0,0)+2\cdot (0,1,0)+0\cdot(0,0,1)\equiv(2,2,0)$
- $-x^2-3=\ldots$

and so on.